# Fix duplicate commits in two branches

Tags: git

Somehow I got into this situation:

Last thing I did was `git rebase production/master`, to be able to push to remote `production`.

But now, I have duplicate commits in `master` and `origin/master`.
So what will happen now if I try to push to `origin/master`, will those double commits appear on remote?

Is there a way to avoid that?

```
o [master] {production/master} redirect to admin dashboard
o hospital edit
o admin dashboard should be fine now
o single date select
o push to trigger post-receive hook
│ o {origin/master} redirect to admin dashboard
│ M─┐ Merge origin/master
│ │ o [feat/dashboard] admin dashboard should be fine now
│ │ o push to trigger post-receive hook
│ o │ hospital edit
│ o─┘ single date select
o─┘ font.css smallfix
```

Comment: honestly you should probably revert back to the commit that your remote branch is on and do a merge instead of a rebase, is there a reason you are doing a rebase in this scenario?

Comment: "Somehow" is because rebase *copies* commits. You (and Git) can't *change* a commit, so to make a new chain of commits that starts at a different point, Git must copy the originals. Then you (and Git) look at the copies instead of the originals. This works fine unless those originals are also being used elsewhere, e.g., as by `origin/master`. This is why you should not normally rebase any shared commits: they get "un-shared".